# How do I find the setting affected by a f-curve using python?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes

Knowing my f-curve, how can I find the animated setting?

```
 bpy.data.actions['Material.001Action'].fcurves[0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer was pretty simple. Just add this at the end of line:

`.data_path`

```
bpy.data.actions['Material.001Action'].fcurves[0].data_path
```

Comment: don't forget the .array_index to tell you which part of location, rotation_euler, or rotation_quaternion the fcurve applies to.

Comment: Thank you Ray Mairlot I cried when I saw that I missed a parameter. I finally found the  .array_index following data block on the outliner ! :')